# Trying to upload a zip file via gradle to local artifactory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

I am trying to get familiar with artifactory in combination with gradle. I am having a testproject which basically only contains a zip file (which is to be uploaded to a local artifactory running in docker) and the gradlefiles for the wrapper + build.gradle file.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.16.0"
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'}
}

configurations {
    generic {
        description = 'generic'
    }
    published
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
            publications('MyZip')
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
}
publishing {
    publications{
        MyZip(MavenPublication) {
            artifact(file("jetty.zip")){
                extension "zip"
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications('MyZip')
}
```

When I execute

```
./gradlew artifactoryPublish
```

It says "Build successful" but only uploads the build info to artifactory, NOT the zip file I want it to upload. I googled and looked the following things:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html

roma77 in this post had the exact same problem but fixed it, didnt work for me tho:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/publish-zip-artifact/5792/2

Also I tried to follow this example https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/gradle-android-example/build.gradle
but that also didnt work.

When I run

```
./gradlew artifactoryPublish --info
```

It says

```
Task ':artifactoryPublish' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
```

Well thats the point I ask you guys because I am pretty much stuck^^ Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit 1:
So after @afterburner suggested a solution I tried it with this build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.16.0"
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java'
}


repositories {
    maven { url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'}
}

configurations {
    generic {
        description = 'generic'
    }
    published
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            publications('myzip')
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
}

task makeZip(type: Zip) {
    from fileTree(dir: 'jetty')
    include '**/*'
    archiveName "jetty.zip"
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/libs/")
    description "Assemble archive $archiveName into ${relativePath(destinationDir)}"
}

publishing {
    publications{
        myzip(MavenPublication) {
            artifact makeZip
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications('myzip')
}
```

in the following I added a buildscript which looked like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${local_user}"
                password = "${local_pw}"
            }
            name = "local"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Found [here](http://buransky.com/scala/publish-jar-artifact-using-gradle-to-artifactory/). It worked ONCE and didn't work anymore after that. Also it uploaded the zip file under gradle/unspecified. Note's to be taken that I would describe my Gradle skills as fairly limited. I think I might be missing some basic configuration for gradle to say what to do.

Log:

```
> Task :artifactoryDeploys an incubating feature.
Deploying build descriptor to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/gradle/1593782379748

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with the following build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle-dev'
            credentials {
                username = "${local_user}"
                password = "${local_pw}"
            }
            name = "maven-main-cache"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}

plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.16.0"
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java'
}

version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'io.klib'

repositories {
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            publications('myzip')
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${local_user}"
            password = "${local_pw}"
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
}

task makeZip(type: Zip) {
    from fileTree(dir: 'jetty')
    include '**/*'
    archiveName "jetty.zip"
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/libs/")
    description "Assemble archive $archiveName into ${relativePath(destinationDir)}"
}

publishing {
    publications{
        myzip(MavenPublication) {
            artifact makeZip
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications('myzip')
}
```

The makeZip task should not be necessary, you can just directly add the file.

I made two basic mistakes here. Firstly, I completely missed the buildscript part, which is crucial for the plugin to know where to push what. Secondly I configured the buildscript part wrong. I wanted to push to the 'gradle-dev-local' repo, because artifactory only allows you to push to local repositories. In the buildscript I used the 'gradle-dev' virtual repository because thats the reachable virtual repository which includes 'gradle-dev-local'. [Virtual repositories include all local, remote and other virtual repositories.](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories)

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past when publishing protobuf files.

```
task protoZip(type: Zip) {
    from "src/main/proto"
    include '**/*.proto'
    archiveName "proto.zip"
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/libs/")
    description "Assemble archive $archiveName into ${relativePath(destinationDir)}"
}


publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact protoZip
        }
    }
}
```

After the new information you've posted, let's break it down step by step. Firstly, it's getting published under `gradle/unspecified` because you haven't set up a `group`, `name`, `version`. In build system speak, you're missing the GAV coordinates: group, artefactId/artefactName and version.
So you'll need to add something like:

```
group = com.stackoverflow.myapp
name = zippy
version = 0.0.1 or something else, depending on how you want to version this
```

Also, try with `gradle publishToMavenLocal` and check your .m2 local repository.

You might have more success after you set the GAV coordinates either way, as I think Artifactory by default is set to not allow artifact overwrite.

Comment: I will try that as soon as possible

Comment: So I tried that, but that still does not work for some reason. Just for testing purposes I extracted the zip I wanted to upload and zipped it with a Task with Gradle. I thought that I needed an artifact as result of a gradle task but that wasn't the right guess.

Comment: @TheECanyon how did you try it and can you post the gradle log please?

Comment: Added a few more things to check, let me know if it helps

Comment: I made some changes, now it works. Firstly tje buildscript part I was missing at the first place is crucial. Secondly one should define the repository in the buildscript correctly. I dont have a plugins-released repository. I changed it do gtadle-dev (NOT LOCAL!) and added version + group. there is some behaviour I do not understand. If I delete the artifact manually, and restart the artifactoryPublish Task, it wont upload it again. I need to `./gradlew clean` to make it upload again. Wil post the solution.